# How does Prisma handle transactions under the hood?

Tags: typescript, types, prisma

How does Prisma handle transactions under the hood?

In their described usage, it almost seems like Prisma has context of the calling code.

```
const write1 = prisma.user.create()
const write2 = prisma.post.create()
const write3 = prisma.profile.create()
await prisma.$transaction([write1, write2, write3])
```

Once, write1 is called, shouldn't the promise already be in the process of being fulfilled? Does it have to do with the fact that the event loop doesn't have the chance to handle the Promise before its passed to $transaction? I just always assumed Prisma already sent the request to the database / underlying engine.

On the type level, things get even more confusing.

```
  async update(id: string, updateBusinessDto: UpdateBusinessDto) {
    if ('financialData' in updateBusinessDto) {
      updateBusinessDto.financialData = await this.mergeFinancialData(
        id,
        updateBusinessDto.financialData,
      )
    }

    return this.prisma.business.update({
      where: { id },
      data: updateBusinessDto,
    })
  }

  async updateFinancialData(id: string, data: Prisma.JsonObject) {
    return this.update(id, {
      financialData: await this.mergeFinancialData(id, data),
    })
  }
```

If I hover over `async update`, it says the return type is `Promise<Business>`. However, if I hover over `this.prisma.business.update` I get `Prisma.Prisma__BusinessClient<Business, never>`. How is it possible for the type to get implicitly casted considering my function is literally returning the result of the Prisma function?

Yet, it doesn't always happen:

```
// This returns Prisma.Prisma__UserClient<User, never>
updateStatus(id: string, status: UserStatus) {
    return this.prisma.user.update({ where: { id }, data: { status } })
}
```

In usage:

```
this.prismaService.$transaction([
        this.userService.updateStatus(user.id, 'CREDIT_DATA_RECEIVED'),
        this.businessService.updateFinancialData(user.business.id, {
         <data>

        // Why is this cast required and why does it work?
        }) as Prisma.PrismaPromise<any>,
      ])
```